# Cannot install dependancies with Laravel 6.9

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to install **barryvdh/laravel-debugbar** from  https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar by doing:

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar --dev
```

I received these errors:

```
c:\wamp64\www\blog>php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 6.9.0

c:\wamp64\www\blog>composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar --dev
Using version ^3.2 for barryvdh/laravel-debugbar
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - way/generators 2.0 requires illuminate/support 4.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[4.1.x-dev, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9].
    - way/generators 2.1 requires illuminate/support 4.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[4.1.x-dev, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9].
    - way/generators 2.2 requires illuminate/support 4.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[4.1.x-dev, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9].
    - way/generators 2.3 requires illuminate/support ~4.1 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[4.1.x-dev, 4.2.x-dev, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.0-BETA1, v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
    - way/generators 2.4 requires illuminate/support ~4.1 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[4.1.x-dev, 4.2.x-dev, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.0-BETA1, v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
    - way/generators 2.5 requires illuminate/support ~4.1 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[4.1.x-dev, 4.2.x-dev, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.0-BETA1, v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
    - way/generators 2.6 requires illuminate/support ~4.1 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[4.1.x-dev, 4.2.x-dev, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.0-BETA1, v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
    - way/generators 2.6.1 requires illuminate/support ~4.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[4.0.x-dev, 4.1.x-dev, 4.2.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.0-BETA2, v4.0.0-BETA3, v4.0.0-BETA4, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.0-BETA1, v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
    - don't install illuminate/support 4.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.10|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.11|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.12|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.14|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.15|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.17|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.18|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.19|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.21|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.23|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.24|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.26|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.27|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.29|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.3|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.30|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.5|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.7|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.9|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support 4.2.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.0-BETA1|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.12|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.16|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.17|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.3|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.5|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.8|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.9|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support 4.0.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.0-BETA2|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.0-BETA3|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.0-BETA4|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.10|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.5|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.6|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.7|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.8|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.9|don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v6.9.0, required as ^6.2) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.9.0].
    - Installation request for way/generators ~2.0 -> satisfiable by way/generators[2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.6.1].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: Share your `composer.json` file

Comment: I can't share it here so I send it on paste bin : https://pastebin.com/sJesPuQu

Comment: one of the library might not be allowing you to do composer, problem lies in your "require-dev":  of composer json, try removing lastone and add debbuger library, then put the removed library again, it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `composer.json` file remove `way/generators` and run `composer update`

```
"require-dev": {
    .....
    "way/generators": "~2.0"", // <-- remove this line
}
```

`way/generators` is for **Laravel 4.2 and Below** version and you are using **Laravel ^6.9**

**Useful link**:
https://packagist.org/packages/way/generators

Comment: Hello I dont find this line in my composer.json file

Comment: remove `way/generators`

Comment: It works now. Thank you ! If you can explain it to me... it would be great !

Comment: edited with explanation,please give up-vote and if you think this is your answer,please mark it as a `answer`- it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You got an error because of this package [way/generators](https://packagist.org/packages/way/generators)

remove **way/generators** in your `composer.json` file

---

Read here: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators

**Laravel 4.2 and Below**

To install this package through Composer you can edit your Composer.json file in this way

```
"require-dev": {
    "way/generators": "~2.0"
}
```

**Laravel 5+**

If you're using Laravel 5 +, then use [this package instead](https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended).

---

**Solution:** You are currently using **Laravel 6.9** so use this package: https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended